# Can't connect java client to elasticsearch server

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to connect my java client to an elasticsearch server.

Elasticsearch 2.4.0 is installed on a distant server.
To access to it, I have to use port 10700. (When I run "telnet xxxx 10700", it worked, so the port is open)

I have an error for 2 days now and I read it could be a conflict between netty4 dependencies, but I'm not able to fix it. (My netty dependencies are transitives, I don't import them by myself)

How can I resolve this problem?

**The java code**:

```
public void connexionToEs() throws UnknownHostException {
    String clusterName = "xxxx";
    String serverAddress = "xxxx";

    try{
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
                .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                .build();
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
        client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(serverAddress), 10700));

        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet();
        String output = response.toString();
        System.out.println(output);
        client.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**The dependencies:**

```
<!-- DEPENDENCIES FOR ELASTICSEARCH CLIENT -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**The error:**

```
Exception in thread "elasticsearch[_client_][management][T#1]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponents(ZLjava/lang/Iterable;)Lio/netty/buffer/CompositeByteBuf;
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.toByteBuf(Netty4Utils.java:78)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.sendMessage(Netty4Transport.java:422)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.sendMessage(Netty4Transport.java:93)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.internalSendMessage(TcpTransport.java:1058)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.sendRequestToChannel(TcpTransport.java:1040)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.executeHandshake(TcpTransport.java:1555)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:502)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.connectToNode(TcpTransport.java:460)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:318)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SniffNodesSampler$1.run(TransportClientNodesService.java:488)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:527)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**The netty4 dependencies:**

```
io.netty:netty:3.10.6.Final
io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.28.Final
io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.28.Final
io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.7.Final
io.netty:netty-common:4.0.28.Final
io.netty:netty-handler:4.0.28.Final
io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.7.Final
io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.28.Final
```

Comment: `<version>5.2.0</version>`...? You aren't running Elasticsearch 5.x

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with 2.4.0 version before, but it doesn't work ...

Comment: Maybe it didn't work because your Netty versions are all over the place? You shouldn't expect 4.x code to work on 3.x base

Comment: I tried to put every netty dependencies in the same version. It doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved a similar problem, with as following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the matching Java dependency for your Elasticsearch server

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this before, but the 2.4.0 elasticsearch-client version doesn't exists...

Comment: Yes it does. I copied from here. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch

Comment: I didn't find it https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/transport

Comment: Oh, okay, then that is probably only a 5.x feature.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right Elasticsearch dependency version - the same as on your server.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, 2.x doesn't require the elasticsearch transport dependency. You can remove

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally, 2.x does not use the PreBuiltTransportClient. See the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.4/transport-client.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error is at the top of the stacktrace:
Exception in thread "elasticsearch[*client*][management][T#1]" **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**: io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponents(ZLjava/lang/Iterable;)Lio/netty/buffer/CompositeByteBuf;

Your code is calling the `addComponents(...)` method of the `io.netty.buffer.ComposityByteBuff` class, but at runtime this method is not available.

Very likely this is due to a different compilation and runtime environment. The versions of the libraries you use to compile your source and the versions of the libraries that are used at runtime are probably not the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude these netty-all dependency. This will fix your issue.

```
compile.exclude group: "io.netty", module:"netty-all"
compile.exclude group: "org.jboss.netty", module:"netty"
```